# Using Mockito spy in one class to Call static method from another class

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

Trying to use Mockito's spy function for my JUnit test. I originally had a Class:

```
public class App1 { 
    public String method1() {
        sayHello();
    }

    public sayHello() {
        Systems.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Everything in my test class was working correctly with mockito spy on above class:

```
@Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void testMethod1Failure(){   
    App1 a1 = spy(App1);
    doThrow(IOException.class).when(a1).sayHello();

    a1.method1();
}
```

But after that i had to switch things around and take sayHello() method into another class to be used as static method:

```
public class App1 { 
    public String method1() {
        App2.sayHello();
    }
}

public class App2 { 
    public static void sayHello() {
        Systems.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

After this change, my original JUnit testcase is broken and i am unsure how i can use Mockito spy to start App1 that calls the external App2 static method... does anyone know how i can do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Mockito does not support mocking static code. Here are some ways to handle it:

- Use PowerMockito or similar framework as suggested here: [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito).
- Refactor your code converting static method back to an instance method. As you've found static methods are not easy to Unit test.
- If it's inexpensive to execute actual static method in question then just call it.

Comment: From Mockito v3.4.0, you can mock static methods without PowerMockito. See for example, https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods